# Resizing Image before converting to Base64 in Django

Tags: django, io, base64

I'm working on a django application which has a "My Profile" section where users can upload there profile images. I'm storing the images as a base64 code and rendering on the site.
This is the code:

```
@login_required
def my_profile_edit(request):    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form =ProfileEditForm(request.POST or None,request.FILES,instance=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            user=form.save(commit =False)
            user.user_image =form.cleaned_data['user_image']
            user.user_image =base64.b64encode(user.user_image.file.read())
            user.user_image ='data:image/jpeg;base64,'+ str(user.user_image)[2:-1]
            user.save()
            return redirect('my_profile')
    profile =CustomUser.objects.get(username=request.user)
    form =ProfileEditForm(instance=profile)
    return render(request,'profile_edit.html',{'form':form,'profile':profile})
```

Though it is working fine, I wish to reduce the size/ resize uploaded image first before encoding it into Base64 to improve performance and reduce space. I've tried few things using StringIO/BytesIO but without success. Please let me know the right way of doing so.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you could process the image with Pillow library like that:

https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.resize

Comment: I was finally able to resolve it using combination of PIL Image library and BytesIO. Thanks for the support!

Answer (score 0):

Finally I was able to resolve this using PIL Image library and BytesIO:

```
@login_required
def my_profile_edit(request):    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form =ProfileEditForm(request.POST or None,request.FILES,instance=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            user=form.save(commit =False)
            user.user_image =form.cleaned_data['user_image']
            
            img = Image.open(user.user_image)
            output = BytesIO()
            img = img.resize( (100,100) )
            img.save(output, format='JPEG', quality=100)
            user.user_image =base64.b64encode(output.getvalue())
            user.user_image ='data:image/jpeg;base64,'+ str(user.user_image)[2:-1]
            user.save()
            return redirect('my_profile')
    profile =CustomUser.objects.get(username=request.user)
    form =ProfileEditForm(instance=profile)
    return render(request,'profile_edit.html',{'form':form,'profile':profile})
```

I did try various variations of io and Image, though was missing `getvalue()` attribute.